# using docusaurus baseUrl, can't start the project locally correctly

Tags: docusaurus

I use docusaurus 2.0.0-alpha.73
When I add baseUrl, page can't be loaded correctly in my local.
This is my code: [git@github.com:WeBeautifulNow/document.git](https://github.com/WeBeautifulNow/document)

This is the correct behavior:

[image: Screen shot of the desired web page]

And this is error behavior in my local.

[image: Screen shot of incorrect web page]

[image: Screen shot of Page Not Found error]

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code in the question itself (ideally as a [mcve]), rather than as an external link?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem... If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to ... then do so - but also **copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Answer (score 0):

Add this in config. Everything is ok

```
baseUrl: process.env.IS_LOCAL ? '/' : 'production base url'
```